# Kendo for jQuery: show one of two different controls in each cell of a grid column

Tags: jquery, dynamic, kendo-ui, controls, creation

I'm using Kendo for jQuery. I have a grid where each cell of a column needs to display either a dropdown control or a text input control. I have found a method here on SO for displaying one or the other in all cells of a given column but not for doing this on a row by row, cell by cell basis.

```
let searchValue = '';
let selectedTab = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // SET UP TAB

    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: {
            open: {
                effects: "fadeIn"
            }
        }
    });

    // RETRIEVE GRID DATA

    const pendingGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: `/pending/Index?searchValue=${searchValue}`,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    }
                })
            },
            create: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/pending/Create",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    }
                })
            },
            update: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/pending/Update",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    }
                })
            },
            destroy: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/pending/Delete",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    }
                })
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "work_date", dir: "desc" },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "cost_index",
                fields: {
                    client_name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    matter: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    narrative: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    cost_type_description: { type: "string" },
                    business_purpose: { type: "string" },
                    venue: { type: "string" },
                    work_date: { type: "date" },
                    post_date: { type: "date" },
                    work_amt: { type: "number" },
                    partner_work_amt: { type: "number", editable: false },
                    timekeeper_name: { type: "string", editable: false }
                }
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "work_date", dir: "desc" }
    });


    // BUILD THE GRID

    const pendingGrid = $("#pending").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: pendingGridDataSource,        
        editable: true, 
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        detailInit: pendingSubGrid,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    narrative: {},
                    cost_type_description: {},
                    client_name: {},
                    matter: {},
                    business_purpose: {},
                    venue: {},
                    work_date: {},
                    post_date: {},
                    work_amt: {},
                    partner_work_amt: {},
                    timekeeper_name: {},                    }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "narrative",
                title: "Narrative",
                width: "300px",
            },
            {
                //field: "cost_type_description",
                //title: "Cost Type Description1",
                field: "cost_type_description",
                title: "Expense Type",
                template: columnTemplateFunction,
                filterable: {
                    operators: {
                        string: {
                            contains: "Contains",
                            eq: "Is equal to",
                            neq: "Is not equal to"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },          
            {
                field: "client_name",
                title: "Client",
                width: "150px",
            },
            {
                field: "matter",
                title: "Matter Number",
                width: "155px",
            },
            {
                field: "business_purpose",
                title: "Purpose",
            },
            {
                field: "venue",
                title: "Venue",
            },
            {
                field: "work_date",
                title: "Expense Date",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "140px"
            },
            {
                field: "post_date",
                title: "Post Date",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "130px"
            },
            {
                field: "work_amt",
                title: "Amount",
                width: "120px",
                format: "{0:c}"
            },
            {
                field: "partner_work_amt",
                title: "Partner Share",
                width: "140px",
                format: "{0:c}"
            },            
            {
                field: "timekeeper_name",
                width: "140px",
                title: "Timekeeper",
            },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy", { text: "Approve", click: ApprovePending }, { text: "Reject", click: RejectPending }], width: "350px" }
        ],
        dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var items = e.sender.items();

            items.each(function (e) {
                var i = 0;
                var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
                var ddt = $(this).find('.dropDownTemplate');
                //if (i == 0) {
                $(ddt).kendoDropDownList({
                    enable: false,
                    value: getET(), //dataItem.value,
                    dataSource: ddlDataSource,
                    dataTextField: "displayValue",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    change: onDDLChange
                });
                //}
                i = i + 1;
            });
        },
        editable: "inline"
    }).data("kendoGrid");

    // VALUES FOR THE DROPDOWNS

    var ddlDataSource = [{
        value: 1,
        displayValue: "Select Expense Type"
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        displayValue: "Gifts"
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        displayValue: "MSG"
    }
    ];

    function getET() {
        return "2"
    };

    function columnTemplateFunction(dataItem) {
        var i = 1;
        if (i == 0)
            var input = '<input class="dropDownTemplate"/>'
        else
            return "<strong>" + kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.name) + dataItem + "</strong>"
        //return "<strong>" + dataItem + "</strong>"
        return input
    };

    function onDDLChange(e) {
        var element = e.sender.element;
        var row = element.closest("tr");
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        dataItem.set("value", e.sender.value());
    };
});
```

Comment: Could you please share some code on what you have done so far?

Comment: trying. it keeps saying i am only posting code.

Comment: ok, there is a bug on SO...it flags incorrectly formatted code and continues to flag it as such even after you have corrected it. you have to start over and insert the corrected code again.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use your minimal working example as I don't have those endpoints. So here's an example where each cell of a column displays either a drop down list or a text box. The meat is in the `editor` function. On the State column, if the Reference is greater than 999 then a drop down list is displayed otherwise a text box is displayed. Should be clear enough in the code. I believe this is what you are looking for as stated in the title "show one of two different controls in each cell of a grid column". Try the code below in the Telerik DOJO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kendo Grid Different Input Control in Column</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  
<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            persistSelection: true,
            selectable: 'cell',
            editable: true,
            dataSource: [{
                reference: 100,
                state: 'Pending',
            },{
                reference: 1000,
                state: 'Pending',
            }],
            columns: [{
                editable: function() { return false; },
                field: 'reference',
                title: 'Reference',
                width: 100,
            },{
                field: 'state',
                title: 'State',
                width: 200,
                attributes: {
                    'title': 'Click to edit',
                },
                editor: function(container, options) {
                    if (options.model.reference > 999) {
                        $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoDropDownList({
                                optionLabel: 'Select Expense Type',
                                dataSource: ['Gifts', 'MSG'],
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoTextBox({
                                
                        });
                    }
                },
            }],
        }).data('kendoGrid');
    });
</script>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The admins marked this one as answered and indeed it was. Thnx for helping me...I hope...making a good impression at my new position!

Comment: @cmabe That's great. If this answer is useful, please upvote and/or mark it as the accepted answer.